# Read a specific memory address via /dev/mem from the command line

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, xilinx

For context, programming a driver to interact with an FPGA IP core on an embedded Linux (Yocto: krogoth) on a Xilinx board.

For debugging purposes I would like to read out specific memory addresses from physical memory. /dev/mem looks promising. I wanted to ask how I can read out the value of a specific physical memory address from the command line. I was hoping for something along the lines of `cat /dev/mem 0x2000000` to read the byte at 0x2000000.

Comment: Search the web for the source code of J.D.Bakker's **devmem2** utility, and build it.  It might even already be built in your Yocto RFS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to devmem2. Found it as a recipe https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/1069/. So I'd just add that to my local.conf file and compile yocto again

Comment: @sawdust What would be the correct procedure to adding my own comprehensive answer if the provided ones only partially cover my use case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually you should already have devmem tool installed in your Linux image:

```
$ devmem 0x2000000
```

If you don't however, you can go to Busybox menu and tweak it to make sure it gets compiled and installed:

```
$ bitbake busybox -c menuconfig
```

(search for devmem)

Comment: At the time of posting the question I did not distinguish the types of memory, physical, io and registers. I posted a more comprehensive question + answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416520/269755) that answers my use case

Answer (score 9):

[Hexdump](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html) is often installed in embedded systems. Then you can do

```
hexdump -C --skip 0x2000000 /dev/mem | head
```

in order to read more than a single word, and see it decoded in various ways.
(The busybox hexdump is a little more limited, but still very useful.)

Comment: Note that busybox hexdump may not support --skip, but has -s instead.

Comment: AFAIK, with hexdump we can only read flash memory. It cannot read I/O peripheral registers.

Comment: @HarshaD Hexdump can only read _files_. To it, `/dev/mem` looks like a file. 
The beauty (or one of them) of unix-like operating systems is that most things can be represented as files.
If you have something (anything, really), that is presented by the OS as a file, hexdump will be able to read it.

Comment: Neither `devmem` nor `hexdump` installed on the Red Pitaya Ubuntu 16 embedded Linux I am using. Tried `dd` piping to `xxd` but could not get it to skip to `0x4020_0000` where my registers are located. `xxd /dev/mem` could have worked if I had the patience to wait 1/2 day for it to scroll to `0x4020_0000`

Comment: I get the error `hexdump: /dev/mem: Operation not permitted`, even when run in a root shell. Is there some kernel setting that disables access to `/dev/mem`, just like SysRq combos can be disabled?

Comment: @Lampe2020
> `hexdump: /dev/mem: Operation not permitted`   --  Yes - apparently you can set `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` to restrict root access to /dev/mem. (There's apparently an IO_STRICT_DEVMEM, which is independent. If that's set to 'n', you should have access to PCI etc, but I haven't tried it.)